# Axios Vue | Как избежать одновременных запросов к серверу

Tags: vue.js, axios

У меня есть 1 индексный компонент, в дереве vue от него идут остальные компоненты, в нём я обращаюсь к серверу через axios для получения данных. Другой vue компонент представляет собою страницу сайта, которая так же сразу же делает запрос к серверу для получения уже своих данных. По итогу выходит так что если я зайду на сайт сразу на страницу этого компонента или же просто обновлю это страницу, оба компонента одновременно сделают запросы к серверу, от чего иногда возникает ошибка 500. Можно просто делать второй запрос после того как мы убедимся что первый закончился, но как сделать так что-бы мы для каждого запроса из разных компонентов не писали каждый раз эту проверку, а это было более автоматически? Как можно без лишнего кода для разных компонентов совершать запросы к серверу после того как закончатся запрос из индексного компонента?